# How to store ASCII code of character in integer in C?

Tags: c, char, int, ascii, warnings

I am working on my C coursework and I need to get char as input and I want to store the ASCII value of that character in int variable. I know this can be done in the following way:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%c", &x);
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

The problem here is that whenever I compile this program in gcc with `-Wformat` enabled, I get this warning:

```
Warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

According to the specifications of the coursework, I would loose some marks if there are any compiler warnings. So, is there any another way I can do the desired task without any compiler warnings?

---

In my actual program, I am scanning in an array and I would also need to store other integers which would be out of the range for char, so I cannot use `char x`

Comment: How about `char x;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a character ASCII value in a integer variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536095/how-to-get-a-character-ascii-value-in-a-integer-variable)

Comment: @Iluvatar Actually, I am scanning an array and I would also need to store other integers which would be out of the range for char, so `char x` won't work for me

Comment: Why not provide a character array ? each index of the array can represent either a digit/character of the input

Comment: @maheshRao Char datatype is only 1 byte long and my program requires me to store integers larger than 1 byte

Comment: @Razin Yes, but what i meant, is that, each index under the char array, can store each digit of the integer. Eg: to store 235, you can use an array, in which a[0]=2,a[1]=3 and a[2]=5,then print out each of them, using a loop.

Comment: @maheshRao The original program performs various complex tasks on those integers so it is not possible to store in the way you are suggesting.

Comment: Ascii values lie only for digits 0-9. For numbers greater than 9,the ascii value is just the concatenation of the ascii values ofeach digit. Eg: 10 would be 4948 in ascii. So, if you want to perform a task over the ascii value of this number, you will have to get the ascii value of each digit, store it in an array and then use a variable of type long or bigger, to store the concatenation of these ascii values. Unless you don't want to perform tasks on the ascii values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    signed char x;
    scanf("%c", &x);
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

Correctly is to define `x` as char but int works as well.

`Char` is defined by the C standard to be a data type able to keep any ASCII character, i.e. at least 127 possible values. The sign does not matter, it is not specified.

If you need to use a char as an integer the best is to define it either with `signed char` or `unsigned char`, depending what you want to do.

On the other hand, `printf("%d\n",x)` will work correcrly because the type coercions will transform the input signed char to integer anyway, as printf%d expects.